# Get HasPublishedVersion property in REST call

Tags: 2013, rest

I am using REST service call to get items. I need to check if the item has any published version in filter part of url. I just need to filter based on this value. I don't need version history. I checked that we have `HasPublishedVersion` property in `SPListItem`.  Is there any similar column that I can use in REST url? or is there any way I can check for published version in REST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following REST URL will give you the byte to indicate whether it is published / is a Draft / is checked out.

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('Serverrelativeurl')?$select=Level
```

And according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx),

> Level: Gets a value that specifies the publishing level of the file. Represents an SP.FileLevel value: Published = 1; Draft = 2; Checkout = 255.

As the items REST endpoint that you are using does not have this property, you could get the server relative URL as below and then feed it into `getfilebyserverrelativeurl` to get the publishing status:

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items?$select=FileRef
```

Comment: It works well except one scenario. when I create a new draft version for published item, it returns me byte value 2. `HasPublishedVersion` gives result true if it has any published version and even its current status is draft.